# How many vertices are in the complete graph with m edges?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graph-theory

I know in a graph with n vertices, there are m = (n(n-1)/2) edges, but in a graph with m edges, how many vertices are there?

Comment: Your school teaches graph theory before quadratic equations?

Comment: As @bof implies, just use that equation for m in terms of n and solve for n. That means solving a quadratic equation. At least, if you mean a complete graph in your question, which you did not quite say.

Comment: @bof I didn't know what to tag it, I

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear in your question if you are assuming that $G$ is a complete graph. In order to answer this accurately, we need to know something more about the graph that contains the $m$ edges.

For example:

- A ***perfect matching*** with $m$ edges has exactly $2m$
  vertices.
- A ***tree*** with $m$ edges has exactly $m+1$ vertices.
- A ***complete graph*** with $m$ edges will have $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}$ vertices.

Generally speaking as the connectivity of $G$ increases for a fixed number of edges, the number of vertices necessarily decreases.